# Converting data between long and wide format using Tidyverse and without

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert from wide format into long format, but can't find good result. The point is that i need to make it in two ways- using packet Tidyverse, and without it, while i have problems with one way.

that is my data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("John", "Anna", "Jonte"),
              Matematyka = c(2, 3, 5),
              Polski = c(5, 5, 4))
```

and i need to convert the data frame into this:

```
 name subject mark
1 John math 2
2 Anna math 3
3 Jonte math 5
4 John eng 5
5 Anna eng 5
6 Jonte eng 4
```

i have something like this, but it have some errors (look down)

`reshape(df2, direction="long", varying = list(names(df2)[2:3]), v.names =list ("subject","mark"),
        idvar = "name")`

but its only in one way... I need to make it using tidyverse and without tidyverse package, any ideas?

```
 Error in min(j) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Comment: The tidyverse has the `gather` and `spread` functions. The reshape2 has `cast` and `melt`.

Comment: Using base `reshape` use:
`r <- reshape(df2, direction="long", varying = list(2:3), 
        timevar = "subject",
        times = names(df2[2:3]),
        v.names = "mark",
        idvar = "name");
rownames(r) <- NULL` and 
`reshape(r, direction = "wide")`
and with dplyr/tidyr use `g <- gather(df2, subject, grade, -name)` and
`spread(g, subject, grade)` .